# Navigation Drawer Intent Activity Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I have created a navigation drawer for an App I'm creating, I'm learning the code and everything as I go along. I've come to a point where I'm unable to make any links to another activity in the navigation drawer work.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    final Button bCreateTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateNewTask);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.Open,      R.string.Close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bCreateTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,                                                   NewTaskActivity.class);
            MainActivity2.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




}
```

**Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.rikhi.chores.MainActivity2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:text="New Task"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnCreateNewTask"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Navigation_Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/nav_accont"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_person_black_24dp"
    android:title="MyAccount"/>
<item android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_settings_black_24dp"
    android:title="settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_lock_outline_black_24dp"
    android:title="logout"/>


</menu>
```

I'm not sure if I have to use intent or how it works if someone could please guide me that would be great. If any other code is needed please ask and ill be happy to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    initNavigationDrawer();

    final Button bCreateTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateNewTask);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, R.string.Open,R.string.Close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    bCreateTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,NewTaskActivity.class);
            MainActivity2.this.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

public void initNavigationDrawer() {

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

            int id = menuItem.getItemId();

            switch (id) {
                case R.id.nav_accont:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_setting:
                    //same logic
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_logout:
                   //same logic
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Also in your layout :

```
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: Ive added it in where you have said however i've got 2 questions. First one is that the R.id.navigation_menu I have to give this xml file a id correct? Second Questoin.... im getting an error at the public void initNavigationDrawer() { saying ; is expected?

Comment: add this:`android:id="@+id/navigation_view"` under ur Navigation view in xml

Comment: Done, however names it navigation_menu if that makes a difference :) How do I get rid of the ; error?

Comment: `navigation_menu`  is not your navigation view id..it is the  menu item file name

Comment: I think I did it, ill explain ive only got 3 xml files for the Navigation Drawer. navgiation Action.xml, navigation Header.xml and Navigation menu.xml. I put what you said inside the mainactivity.xml under the navigation view?

Comment: Awesome its working, appreciate the help very much :)

Comment: Im not sure ive up-voted it, no reason to down vote youve helped me to make it work, hmmmm someone else didnt like the answer or something. Very sorry about it. Any chance you could help me with something else? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205073/capture-image-upload-to-firebase-and-retrieve-java-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

```
bCreateTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, NewTaskActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I understand that and will correct however that a separate button within the screen, I am trying to make the navigation drawer link to other activities.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. You should probably [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42180704/edit) your previous answer and add this as an addendum rather than make a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add drawer, then you have to use this way.

```
     @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
     @Override
     public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();

      if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

      } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {

      } else if (id == R.id.nav_study_list) {

      }
      DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
      return true;
     }
```

Comment: How would I make lets say nav_home link to MainActivity2?

Comment: For a simplicity, if you are using Android Studio, then right-click on the src folder, and select Activity--->NavigationDrawer.

Comment: Can I do this put the intent inside the if(id == R.id.nav_home)?