# Capture Image, Upload To Firebase And Retrieve Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am very sorry if this may be a question with a simple solution.

**What Am I Trying To Do?**

- Capture an image from a Button
- Upload that image to Firebase storage
- Retrieve that image in an ImageView

**What Is My Trouble So Far?**

- Takes picture, but crashes when I click the tick.
- Hence nothing is being uploaded or being achieved.

**My Code**

P.N I have looked at lots of other forums and video tutorials but nothing seems to be working. Hopefully someone can help.

```
public class LeaderboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
    private StorageReference mStorage;

    private ProgressDialog mProgress;

    String mCurrentPhotoPath;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_leaderboard);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        final Button bImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCamera);
        final ImageView ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

        bImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);


            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            mProgress.setMessage("Uploading Image");
            mProgress.show();

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Photo").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < UploadTask.TaskSnapshot > () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(LeaderboardActivity.this, "Uploading Complete...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                }
            });
        }
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName, /* prefix */
            ".jpg", /* suffix */
            storageDir /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File

            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.android.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Error In Android Monitor**

Not sure if this will help

```
02-13 02:30:32.693 2133-2133/com.example.rikhi.chores E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process:  com.example.rikhi.chores, PID: 2133
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.rikhi.chores/com.example.rikhi.chores.LoginRegister.InsideMainActivity.LeaderboardActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4089)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getLastPathSegment()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.rikhi.chores.LoginRegister.InsideMainActivity.LeaderboardActivity.onActivityResult(LeaderboardActivity.java:74)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6932)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4085)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4132) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1533) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I have looked at other people who had the same problem, followed what they said nothing happend, followed the Google Android instructions for this and again same problem.

Comment: I don't use firebase but it's very much simple to upload photo to a server with HTTP multipart request using AsyncHttpClient

Comment: Ahh, unfortunately, i'm just starting out with Android Studio and have already created a database for login and users just trying to get this to work is the last step XD but thank you ill have a look at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On button, click remove that intent and just call your
   `dispatchTakePictureIntetnt()` method on Onclick button Listener
2. Also, check go to your emulator settings, and check your camera
   permission is on for your this app and also go to firebase console
   and check the rules if, rules are not equal to null made them equal
   to null then run your app because `!=null` rules only work when there
   is an authentication method in your app